# What does ConstraintSet.Constraint::margin refer to?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I call

```
constraintSet.connect(viewId, START, leftId, leftId == 0 ? START : END, margin);
```

Which I see sets:

```
constraintSet.constraint.leftMargin = margin;
```

But what does this `constraintSet.constraint.leftMargin` mean?

Margins are set to views. What is the effect of margins to a `constraint` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The margin between this view's left edge and the view it's *constrained to*. For example, if this was constrained to its parent, the left margin would be specifying how much *gap* between the left edge of this view and its parent.

Comment: does it override the view's original margin? or adds to it?

Comment: I believe it adds to it but don't hold me to it!